# How to move Sticky Notes from taskbar to tray on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

Sticky Notes seems very useful and I want to use it for my day to day tasks.

But when I open Sticky Notes, it always sits in the taskbar. If I could move it to the System Tray, then that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Windows 7's Sticky Notes cannot be minimised to the tray. Either of the following should work (the first adds this missing feature among others, the second is a 3rd party notes utility with this feature):

### 1. [Sticky Notes Taskbar Hider](http://drakendev.com/sticky-notes-taskbar-hider.htm)

[image] [image] [image]

### 2. [Stickies](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/)

[image] [image]

Comment: unfortunately I can't install these software's in my system (no admin permissions )

Comment: Can you try [Stickies Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/stickies_portable) and see if it works fine?

Comment: Sophos is blocking the SNTH site as having been flagged for malware. Any insight?

Comment: @isherwood: No idea. Maybe the site *is* infected, perhaps after being hacked. Maybe it's just a bad ad. Maybe it's a Sophos false positive. I'm sure the program is available elsewhere as well.